# cvs delete project (module) and reclaim space

Tags: disk-space, cvs

We have modules under CVSROOT that were created a while ago, but no more required/ever used or needed. They are just sitting there are consuming disk space.

Is it safe to physically delete this location from OS command line? Or is there any standard way to remove projects and reclaim space?

Comment: Migrate to a real VCS.  Seriously, using CVS in this day and age is like still using Windows 3.1.  CVS was god awful 10 years ago when it was replaced with svn, and there are several newer systems that are leaps and bounds better than that.  bzr attempts to be user friendly and easy to use for those used to cvs or svn, though I found git to be more powerful once you get over the learning curve.

Comment: @psusi - if it was up to me I would. But look at the mess there are at least 10 different projects on this cvs.. getting all devs to learn new technology for version control? forget it

Comment: I believe `git` would let any masochists pretend to still use `cvs`, maybe others would too.

Comment: It's real easy to get the devs to learn new technology: tell them their job depends on it ;)